# What is the Best Way to Keep Bootstrap Columns All of Even Height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The image below come from [this url](http://launchpad-001.com/_firingRange/hlows/bstudy-flextitle.php).

What is the best way to make all the columns in a Bootstrap keep themselves at the same height, given that the content within the columns can vary in height?   What is needed is  a style that says, "make this this column at least as tall as the tallest column in this row."
[image: Columns 1-9 are too short for the row]
[image: Columns at this width, same page, are all the same height. Nice.]

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox** is your friend!

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

#container div {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 2</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box Box Box Box 3</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 4</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 5</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 6</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 7</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 8</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 9</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 10</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box 11</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"><p>Box Box 12</p></div>
</div>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/9gapcjem/)